# command execute with error when use expect in shell script while work fine in pure shell

Tags: bash, docker, expect

I try to start all the exited docker containers deployed in separated servers, so basically i should execute the essential command below

```
[ $(docker ps -a | grep Exited | wc -l) -ne 0 ] && docker start $(docker ps -a | grep Exited | cut -d' ' -f1)
```

It worked fine like in pure linux shell , but then error occured(show below) when i try to use expect to "send" the "essential" command. (local ip is 241,remote end is 209)

```
[root@localhost start_shell_dir]# spawn ssh root@192.168.1.209
root@192.168.1.209's password:
Last login: Fri Oct 15 22:23:25 2021 from 192.168.1.241
[root@localhost ~]# invalid command name "0"
    while executing
"0 -ne 0 "
    invoked from within
"send "[ 0 -ne 0 ] && docker start ""
```

The error log shows i have already log in the remote machine, and something wrong when i execute the docker command.
[Glenn jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7552/glenn-jackman) from the comment area shows me the [basic rule for tcl](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm),then i realize expect does command substitutions before sending real command. We may see it from execute `bash -x script.sh` .

```
[root@localhost start_shell_dir]# bash -x startContainer.sh
+ read ip pass
+ read ip pass
+ /usr/bin/expect
[root@localhost start_shell_dir]# ++ docker ps -a
++ grep Exited
++ wc -l
++ docker ps -a
++ grep Exited
++ cut '-d ' -f1
spawn ssh root@192.168.1.209
root@192.168.1.209's password:
Last login: Fri Oct 15 22:37:56 2021 from 192.168.1.241
[root@localhost ~]# invalid command name "0"
    while executing
"0 -ne 0 "
    invoked from within
"send "[ 0 -ne 0 ] && docker start ""
```

Anyway, the final command that work for me is the command showed below(replace double quotes with braces and with backslash before $() to keep it as an ordinary character rather than pre-parse it).

```
send {[ \$(docker ps -a | grep Exited | wc -l) -ne 0 ] && docker start \$(docker ps -a | grep Exited | cut -d' ' -f1)}
```

```
#!/bin/bash
# my original script with error
while read ip pass
do
                {
                /usr/bin/expect <<-END
                spawn ssh root@$ip
                expect {
                "yes/no" { send "yes\r";exp_continue }
                "password:" { send "$pass\r" }
                }
                expect "#"
                send "[ $(docker ps -a | grep Exited | wc -l) -ne 0 ] && docker start $(docker ps -a | grep Exited | cut -d' ' -f1)"
                expect eof
                END
                }&

done<apps_ip.txt
```

Comment: you need to learn [tag:tcl] first to use Expect. try my [sexpect](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect/) if you are more comfortable with shell syntax.

Comment: What's the actual error?  (You seem to have included a link to a PNG file instead of the error message.)  Can you use a general-purpose automation tool like Ansible or Salt Stack instead of writing this script?

Comment: I'm new to expect even shell ,and have no intention right now to go deep like learning Ansible or Salt Stack. Writing this script is more like for fun，LOL

Answer (score 0):

Like the shell, Tcl (and expect) allows interpolation with double quotes. Tcl uses square brackets for command substitution (in the same way that the shell uses `$(...)`)

Use curly braces to protect the contents of that string (analogous to the shell's single quotes):

```
send {[ $(docker ps -a | grep Exited | wc -l) -ne 0 ] && docker start $(docker ps -a | grep Exited | cut -d' ' -f1)}
#....^.............................................................................................................^
# and don't forget to hit Enter
send "\r"
```

See https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm for the few syntax rules of Tcl.

Comment: Thx for your reply. The [document](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm) validates my assumption that expect do pre-parse(command substitutions) for me. As i wish docker command is executed in remote machine , i add the backslash to treat it as an ordinary character.So my final command would be:  ```send {[ \$(docker ps -a | grep Exited | wc -l) -ne 0 ] && docker start \$(docker ps -a | grep Exited | cut -d' ' -f1)}```

Comment: Using braces means you don't need the backslashes.

Comment: emmm, here is the thing，say i have two machine whose ip are 10.0.0.1 and 10.0.0.2 respectively.  I execute my shell script (contain expect command  : `spawn ssh user@10.0.0.2 ` and `send {echo $(hostname -I) }`  )on 10.0.0.1 ，which means i want to print 10.0.0.2.  However i got 10.0.0.1 , is it only i change the command to `send {echo \$(hostname -I) }`(with backslash) then it print 10.0.0.2.

Comment: @zjh_Leo, heredocs with an unquoted sigil, like `<<EOF`, are _always_ processed by the shell before `expect` can ever see them (so it's not `expect` that runs command substitution and parameter expansions, it's the copy of bash that later starts expect). You'd need to use `<<'EOF'` or `<<\EOF` to prevent that. Replace `expect` with `cat` to see what you're actually sending to expect as source code after the shell does its thing.